# Summarization in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a newbie to Elasticsearch. We are currently using Splunk platform for our analytics application and looking to migrate to ELK. Splunk provides options to schedule searches to run in background periodically and to store the search results in a separate summary index. Is similar functionality available in Elasticsearch? If so, please point me to the documentation containing the process.

Thanks,

Keerthana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great use case. Of course Elasticsearch can perform such tasks, but it is more manual. You have to write your own script. So for example, if you want to summarize data, you can use ElasticSearch aggregations, and take the result (which comes in JSON format) and store it back into an index where you keep summary data. This way, even if you delete your raw data, your summary data lives on.

Elasticsearch comes with different clients. I like to use the Python Elasticsearch DSL library.